# PYTHONOF error while using jedi-vim

Tags: jedi-vim

if you get a

```
E492: Not an editor command: Python << PYTHONEOF
```

or a

```
import jedi
ImportError: No module named jedi
```

Answer (score 0):

**go into your /jedi-vim folder and run**
    git submodule update --init

**also add**

```
if has('python')
    command! -nargs=1 Python python <args>
else
    command! -nargs=1 Python python3 <args>
end
```

to jedi-vim/autoload/jedi.vim

Comment: please accept your own answer, if you think it's good enough. Apart from that: I don't think you should add something to `autoload/jedi.vim`. But in any way you have to install `Jedi`.